# Locally compact, complete, bounded spaces

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Is every locally compact, complete, bounded space compact?

It seems that this fact is implicitly used in the definition of Gromov-Hausdorff convergence for pointed spaces on wikipedia, but I'm not able to prove it.

Comment: Do you mean *Metric* space?

Comment: You talk about metric spaces, I assume?  Otherwise I wouldn't know what completeness and boundedness mean.  Moreover, by boundedness, do you just mean that the metric is bounded?  Discrete spaces are locally compact and carry complete bounded metrics without being compact.
 

Comment: By bounded, do you mean finite diameter, or totally bounded?  This affects whether or not your question is true.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is true. For example, take an *infinite* set and put discrete metric on it, that is, $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $d(x,y)=1$ if $x\not=y$. Then I believe this is locally compact, complete and bounded, but it is not compact. Did I understand your question correctly?

Answer (score 0):

A metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded.  This is the Heine-Borel theorem.  Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: If every complete and totally bounded space is compact, then a countable union of finite sets is always countable.

Comment: Certainly true, the implication that you state, its antecedent, and also the conclusion.  Can you elaborate what you want to say in your comment?

Comment: The implication is provable in ZF, unlike the conclusion.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification.
